# Problems with WordPress + ngrok, I use WAMPServer

Tags: wordpress, wamp, wampserver, ngrok

I am using ngrok to display WordPress sites on the internet but I have a problem:

- I am using: `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localdomain.com-dev:80`
- I put this configuration in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://xxx.ngrok.io');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://xxx.ngrok.io');
```

When connect to ngrok

And when I want to enter the site, it is redirected infinitely in the home/root (that is, it is redirected when entering **xxx.ngrok.io**), when I access a page like **xxx.ngrok.io/page** it can be seen, but the home do not.

Is there any solution?

I am using WAMPServer in my page.

Comment: Can you check admin dashboard settings

Comment: Yes @vadivela I can check